# How to disable adding JPQL alias in pageable / sort in spring data?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using @Query in my dao like this:

`@Query("select e, f from Employee e, Family f "
            + "where e.employeeId = f.employeeId")
 public List<Object[]> getAll(Sort sort);`

As noted, I don't use @onetomany / @manytoone in Employee and Family.

I have a problem when I want to sort a property of Family entity.
Suppose that famChildName is a property in Family entity.

So, in my service layer, I call like this:

`Sort sort = new Sort(new Sort.Order("famChildName"));
dao.getAll(sort);`

When, I see the generated JPQL:

`select e, f from entity.Employee e, entity.Family f 
where e.employeeId = f.employeeId order by e.famChildName asc`

What a surprised, since spring data add alias "e.famChildName".
I even try to send parameter in sort "f.famChildName". But, still no luck since spring data also add alias : "e.f.famChildName".

My question: How to disable Spring data to automatically add alias to sort properties?? Any workaround for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there no one can answer/solve my question??

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the exact same issue. I created a bug report for it and it turns out it's been fixed in the snapshot releases, so will likely be fixed in the next release of Spring Data JPA.

Here's the bug that I submitted

https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-726

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.

I've tried 1.7.3 snapshot release. Unfortunately, it got same errors.
FYI, in my case, I don't use any relation like @ onetomany / @ manytoone.

Any suggestion?

Comment: @uskrip In my case I am using the annotations so I can't really help there. Maybe file a bug with spring. They were pretty quick getting back to me.